# Google Analytics - Custom Dimensions sent to wrong website's google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have two google analytic views setup like below:

1. Website's URL: abc-x1.test.com
2. Website's URL: abc-x2.test.com

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBXNo.png)

The urls are different by subdomains and they are separate web applications.

I added ga tags, ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto'), in both web applications and every time a button is clicked it sends some custom dimensions.

The problem that I'm having is even though I clicked the button in the first website (abc-x1), it sends dimension information to both websites' google analytics. (or not sure if it's sending it to both but I can see the dimensions coming in in both views when I do query).

How can I send custom dimensions to the website where I clicked the button but not to the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a filter based on domain for each views. The website entered in you screenshot is not used to distinguish the site data, it has another function in reports but has no impact on the data.

Comment: Thanks, adding a filter worked. But, what's the purpose of the website's url in the view page then?

Comment: It is appended to the page path when you click on the square icon in the displayed pages, to open a popup of the site page preview.